# How to programmatically click on cross button X c#

Tags: c#, winforms

i searched google lot to know how can i programmatically click on cross button X using c#. i got the below code which is used for different purpose.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    if (string.Equals((sender as Button).Name, @"CloseButton"))
        // Do something proper to CloseButton.
    else
        // Then assume that X has been clicked and act accordingly.
}
```

so anyone can tell me How to programmatically click on cross button for closing form. thanks

Comment: Can the CloseReason enum help you to distinguish the way the form is closed?

Comment: i just like to know how programmatically we can click on cross button or form close button using c#.

Comment: What if user is shutting Windows down? Or closing the application with Task Manager? On the other hand: do you really want to ditinguish mouse click on "X" and, say, Alt+F4 from keyboard?

Comment: If you want to emulate close click investigate [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx) to send WM_CLOSE to you window.

Comment: @ lavrik i guess sendmessage will work.

Answer (score 1):

To check the close reason you can use the `CloseReason` enum

```
private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall)
        // Do something...
}
```

If you want to programattically close a form you can use

```
this.Close();
```

This will launch the `FormClosing` event that is displayed above.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to emulate close click investigate [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx) to send WM_CLOSE to you window.